# How to prerender a component in react-navigation before switching to it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Inside my StackNavigator, one of the components includes web content with a long loading time. However, this screen will only be shown late in my navigation flow.
How can I use this time to render my component in the background before finally switching to it?

I couldn't find anything comparable to ReactDOM.render in React Native that would allow me to render it manually.

Comment: You can use the indicator to create a loading screen

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't make a difference in waiting time

Comment: Did you find any good solution to this problem? I am also faced with same problem

Comment: No, if you're able to switch to Cordova. In the meantime I realized how ridiculous react-native and the ecosystem. Nobody cares about real performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any option in react-navigation to preload a screen that is not displayed, except maybe when the screen is part of a tab navigator.

Depending on what is slowing down the rendering, you might be able to do some actions in the first screen and later pass the results to the second screen using a navigation parameter.

For instance, if you are fetching data from an api in the second screen, you could fetch this data in the first screen and pass it to the second one:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', { data: this.data });
```

If it is a component, you could also try to build it in the first screen and pass it in the same fashion:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', { component: this.component });
```

If you are rendering a WebView in the second screen, what can help is to render the WebView in the first screen too, but with no width or height. The WebView will not be displayed but the website data will be fetched and cached, making the real render more efficient:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native' }} style={{ height: 0, width: 0 }} />
      {this.renderCurrentScreen()}
    </View>
  );
}
```